# Self sign certificate for external website

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

TLS handshake for some websites is really slow. (Let it be www.example.com) (I don't own the website)

I was thinking if I could self sign certificate for www.example.com, this could speed up the process (something similar to --no-check-certificate in wget)

PS: I'm aware of the potential security risks associated.

Comment: What exactly is your question? For what it's worth I 1) find it surprising that the TLS handshake is slow. I would figure out why that is and fix that. 2) I don't believe a self-signed certificate would fix handshake performance. Most of the "slow" part of the handshake is ephemeral key generation and a few network roundtrips, neither of which a self-signed cert addresses 3) if you are aware of the security risks then why are you using TLS at all? A self-signed cert and using `--no-check-certificate` means anyone could MITM the handshake and present this own certificate.

Comment: @vcsjones actually the website is github.com and the issue is with our network provider only. I have tried different systems, os and browsers. Is there a way to disable SSL for a particular website that would speed up website loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly provide your own certificate for the TLS handshake with a website you don't control.

But you might have some SSL intercepting proxy where the connection between this MITM proxy and the client is authenticated by your custom certificate. Only, the connection between the proxy and the server is still authenticated by the servers original certificate, so you've likely just moved the slow handshake problem from your client to your proxy but will be ultimately affected by it the same way.

Comment: I have verified the certificate shown by the website. It is same as originally issued. I think this removes the possibility of ssl interception

Comment: @user56036: I'm not suggesting SSL interception as attack but as a way to use your own certificate for the connection from client.